# BaseStore and BaseSite in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am new in hybris and I want to know how Basesite,Basestore,site and store are different from each other. And can one base site have multiple basestore and vice versa.

Comment: refer to this [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) I see you have not accepted an answer to many of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

From [Overview of the CMS2 Data Model](https://help.sap.com/viewer/86dd1373053a4c2da8f9885cc9fbe55d/1905/en-US/8b7cdc55866910149b09c285e4c2b1ed.html):

> A CMSSite is the entry point to a website. A CMSSite is assigned to
>   one or more stores, known as base stores, which define the product
>   catalogs and the versions that should be available in the website.

You can treat BaseStore as a physical shop, and a BaseSite/CMSSite as a website. A site can cater different stores. The relationship between BaseStore and BaseSite is many-to-many.